# Referencing or Creating a Drawable from its Res ID (Int) Value?

Tags: android, resources, drawable, android-resources, android-drawable

I would like to be able to store a drawables INT value (ResourceID) in SQLite and later be able to pull it from the database and convert it to a drawable to be viewed in a listview.

The following snippit generates 2 values, the ResID portion is a int value that I would like to be able to convert back to the drawable in another activity.\

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                    images[position]);
            Log.e("DRAWABLE", "DrawableId 1:   " + myDrawable);
            int resId = images[position];
            Log.e("DRAWABLE", "DrawableId 2:   " + resId);
```

**What should I do to convert ResID to a drawable? If possible**

**PicturePickerFragment**

```
public class PicturePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

ListView listView;
ArrayList<RowItem> rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
// attach adapter to a list view
// A String[] array that will hold the names of the items.
public static final String[] descriptions = { "Baby", "Baking",
        "Barbershop", "Camping", "Conference Call", "Funeral", "Gambling",
        "Gardening", "Halloweeen", "Medicine", "Meeting", "Poker",
        "Christmas", "Wedding" };
public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.baby,
        R.drawable.baking, R.drawable.barbershop, R.drawable.camping,
        R.drawable.conferencecall, R.drawable.funeral, R.drawable.gambling,
        R.drawable.gardening, R.drawable.halloween, R.drawable.medicine,
        R.drawable.meeting, R.drawable.poker, R.drawable.santa,
        R.drawable.wedding };

Button btn_pic;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View convertView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);

    // defining the alertdialog
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setView(convertView);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.event_type);

     builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.select_picture,
     new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     // call the method on the parent activity when
     // user click the positive button

     }
     });

    // populating the array list
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], descriptions[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    // defining listview and using array adapter
    listView = (ListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment2);
    DrawableAdapter adapter = new DrawableAdapter(getActivity(), rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                int position, long id) {

            // final int item = images[position];
            Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(
                    images[position]);
            Log.e("DRAWABLE", "DrawableId 1:   " + myDrawable);
            int resId = images[position];
            Log.e("DRAWABLE", "DrawableId 2:   " + resId);
            Button b = (Button) getActivity()
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_picture);
            b.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, myDrawable,
                    null, null);
        }

    });

    adapter.addAll(rowItems);

    return builder.create();
}
}
```

**CreateActivity**

```
public class CreateActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

EditText etTitle;
Button btDate;
Button btTime;
Button btPic;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    //onclicklistener
    findViewById(R.id.btn_confirm).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_back).setOnClickListener(this);

    etTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTitle);
    btDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_date);
    btTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_time);
    btPic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_picture);

}

// Will be called via the onClick attribute
// of the buttons in main.xml
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.btn_confirm:
        String title = etTitle.getText().toString();
        String time = btTime.getText().toString();
        String date = btDate.getText().toString();


        Drawable drawable = btPic.getCompoundDrawables()[1];
        int 


        Log.e("DRAWABLE", "DrawableId 3:   " + drawable);
        //Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap();


        Log.e("LOG", title);
        Log.e("LOG", time);
        Log.e("LOG", date);


        Bundle newBundle = new Bundle();
        newBundle.putString("TITLE", title);
        newBundle.putString("TIME", time);
        newBundle.putString("DATE", date);
        //newBundle.putInt

        //Trying to pass a drawable from one activity to another
        //newBundle.putParcelable("DRAWABLE", bitmap);


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtras(newBundle);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();

        break;

    case R.id.btn_back:
        finish();
        break;
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

public void showPicturePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new PicturePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "picturePicker");
}

}
```

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {

ListView listView;
int lastIndex = -1;
ArrayList<Event> lstEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();

// detail view
TextView tvTitle, tvTime, tvDate;
ImageView ivPic;
View vw_master;

boolean _isBack = true;

ImageButton add;

String title;
String date;
String time;
int resId;

static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // // get detail controls
    tvTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    tvDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
    tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewTime);
    ivPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(this);


    /////////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    /////////////////////////////////LISTVIEW////////////////////////////////////////




    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();

    adapter.addAll(events);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();






}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.add:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
    // /////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////

    // Create the adapter to convert the array to views
    EventAdapter adapter = new EventAdapter(this, lstEvents);

    // attach adapter to a list view
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFragment);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    if (requestCode == 100) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle b = data.getExtras();
            title = b.getString("TITLE");
            time = b.getString("TIME");
            date = b.getString("DATE");

            // retrieving bitmap from CreateActivity
            int drawable = b.getInt("DRAWABLE");
            //Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) b.getParcelable("DRAWABLE");

            // converting from bitmap to drawable
            //Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

            // Event newEvent = new Event();
            // newEvent.set_date(date);
            // newEvent.set_title(title);
            // newEvent.set_time(time);

            // set drawable
            // newEvent.set_drawable(drawable);

            // lstEvents.add(newEvent);

            // adapter.addAll(lstEvents);
            // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            ///////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
            /**
             * CRUD OPERATIONS
             */

            Log.e("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
            db.addEvent(new Event(0, title, time, date, drawable));

            // Reading all contacts
            Log.e("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
            // List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();
            List<Event> events = db.getAllContacts();
            adapter.addAll(events);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //logging all events

            for (Event ev : events) {
                String log = "Id: " + ev.get_Id() + " ,Title: "
                        + ev.get_title() + " ,Date: " +           ev.get_date();
                // Writing Contacts to log
                Log.e("Name: ", log);

            }

            ///////////////////////////////DATABASE/////////////////////////////////////////////
        }

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe storing the `Resource Id` is not the right approach, since `Id's` are only `unique` to each type of resource. So there are possible of same `Id` for two different resources.

The best approach would be to store the file name of resource as string.

You can retrieve the resource id with the resource file name using `Resource Identifier`

```
 int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("file_name", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Is it possible to retrieve the "file_name", "drawable" and so on without actually knowing what the user is going to select? I am confused as to whether those are generic strings or if they have to correspond to an exact drawable name? 

My situation is an interesting one. The drawable is being set to a regular button and than I am trying to pass that drawable through a bundle to the MainActivity where I would use it and some other values passed (title, date, etc.) to create an object and save it into an SQLite DB.

I have included more code to further explain.

Comment: In this approach You have to know the drawable name, and save the name in database.

Comment: So what would you suggest doing to be able to reference the drawable that is used with the button? When I populate the listview it should be able to pull from the database and create "Events" which are comprised of Title, Date, Time, Drawable. I have the 3 Strings working, the drawable is giving me the most trouble.

Comment: Have the drawable name in database. And when you populate the listView retrieve the drawable name and as i said retrieve the resource id of the drawable . Now with the id you can get the exact drawable getResources().getDrawable(resourceId)